# OOP classes design

Tags: java, oop, if-statement

My question concerns classes design in OOP. Let say we have ItemBase which is parent class for Canceled, Modified and Added class. We also have DueToBase class - parent of Provider and Distributor.

---

[image: simple diagram]

---

ItemBase may be changed due to DueToBase class.

Assume that ItemBase has property of type DueToBase, and DueToBase has interface method called compute(). Compute algorithm is **RELATED** to the specific ItemBase derived class. So we have six different possible combinations of ItemBase-DueToBase relationship.

Example.

```
ItemBase ib = new Added();
ib.changed = new Provider(ib);
ib.changed.compute();
```

My question is how should relationship between ItemBase and DueToBase be built in real object oriented programming ? I do not see swich/case or if condition clause in compute method for checking which type of instance ItemBase is. 
It gets even worse if DueToBase has another XXXBase class inside which has another interface method YYY() which algorithm depends on the specific instance of DueToBase (and even on the ItemBase). 
How to deal with such cases ? Is there any good programming pattern for such things ? Maybe direction I followed is bad. I would appreciate for your assistance.

maybe that my diagram was not clear. The problem is with following... 
pseudocode:

```
doSomething(){
   if(itemBase instanceof Cancelled){
      if(dueToBase instanceof Provider)
         algorithm1();
      else if(dueToBase instanceof Company)
         algorithm2();
   }else if(itemBase instanceof Modified){
      if(dueToBase instanceof Provider)
         algorithm3();
      else if(dueToBase instanceof Company)
         algorithm4();
   }else if(itemBase instanceof Added){
      if(dueToBase instanceof Provider)
         algorithm5();
      else if(dueToBase instanceof Company)
         algorithm6();
   }
}
```

it gets even worse with deeper if clauses.

Comment: have a look at dependency injection as a concept

Comment: I know what DI and IoC are but these has nothing to do with my question. I am asking how to deal with nested conditions for choosing appropriate action

Comment: have you tried the strategy pattern? Looks like it should fit.

Comment: For future reference, you should read a design patterns book. One I recommend would be Head First Design Patterns

Comment: @kkris1983, How did you end up solving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the better way will be:

```
interface Algorithm {

    void executeAlgorithm();

}
```

and have classes, that implement Algorithm interface, instead of functions. Algorithm1, Algorithm2, Algorithm3 and so on.

and have table:

```
Algorithm[,] algorithmTable = { { new Algorithm1(), new Algorithm2() },
                                { new Algorithm3(), new Algorithm4() },
                                { new Algorithm5(), new Algorithm6() }
                              };
```

and have maps

```
Map< Class<?> , Integer > itemBaseMap = new HashMap<>();

Map< Class<?> , Integer > dueToBaseMap = new HashMap<>();
```

and somewhere build this maps

```
itemBaseMap.add( Canceled.class , 0 );
itemBaseMap.add( Modified.class , 1 );
itemBaseMap.add( Added.class , 2 );

dueToBaseMap.add( Provider.class, 0 );
dueToBaseMap.add( Company.class, 1 );
```

and in doSomething method you can write

```
void doSomething( ItemBase itemBase, DueToBase dueToBase ) {
    Integer itemBaseIndex = itemBaseMap.get( itemBase.getClass() );
    Integer dueToBaseIndex = dueToBaseMap.get( dueToBase.getClass() );

    Algorithm algorithm = algorithmTable[ itemBaseIndex, dueToBaseIndex ];

    algorithm.executeAlgorithm();
}
```

Comment: this is better way than one which I wrote here, because in this answer
Algorithm interface is not depended on dueToBase or anything.

Answer (score 4):

Your `ItemBase` class can be an abstract class with `compute()` method in it, and all the child classes can have their own implementation.

So later you can do something like this,

```
ItemBase ib = new Added();
ib.changed = new Provider(ib);
ib.changed.compute();
```

Now, when you will call compute method on `ib.changed`, it will execute compute implementation of `Added` class.

---

In your case, due to base class, Add a instance variable which distinguish between `Provider` and `Company`. Something like a `boolean` flag or `int`.

Then instead of using `dueToBase instanceof Provider` you can just create if statement. So your updated pseudo code will decreased to few line. Something like this,

```
doSomething(){
      if(dueToBase.isProvider) {
         algorithm1(); //execute if Provider
      } else { 
         algorithm2(); //execute if Company
      }
}
```

Now the complexity to choose compute will be handled by Abstract pattern and then you just have to worry about whether it is company or provider.

Comment: I understand polymorphism concept but my question is 'how to deal with nested conditions for choosing appropriate action'.

Comment: As you mentioned earlier, In real world you should not check instanceof to execute some code. The method should be called naturally. I guess the design of ItemBase and DueToBase needs to be more clear. We can only debug design if the requirement are in front of us, by requirement I mean the entire description of system :(

Comment: I think this solves the problem, you are using kind of 2 strategy patterns in which you will have the specific implementations of both the specific classes available. Unless you can't abstract the algorithm in the relevant pieces.

Comment: my bad was that I mentioned inheritance in the description which may be bad conception at all. Question is how to divide/arrange nested if clauses for choosing specific action using OOP.

Comment: @GriffinHeart I was thinking about Strategy pattern which would be choosen on specific combination of ItemBase and DueToBase, but it gets messy if I add another level of nested if clauses under DueToBase. Is there any better solution for this ?

Comment: @kkris1983, I have just updated the answer, and the other thing when you say you want to solve this with OOP that means you want remove the procedure language type complexity like if statements and you want solution by using Abstract class, Inheritence, Interface etc. which are basically OOP concepts or tools :)

Comment: @Owl and that is exactly what I want to avoid :) because if there is another level of conditions in algorithm1 which checks every combination of ItemBase/DueToBase derived classes to choose correct action, then I will stuck in another lvl of even more complicated conditionals. And yes I agree I have to use inheritance and other ways that OOP brings to avoid procedure programming. But imo in that case inheritance just does not fit :/

Comment: So try the method I suggested, Just create a sample app and check whether it works as you desire.

Comment: I do not have to try it because I really understand where it leads to.
Lets add another SomethingBase class which is parent of SomethingA and SomethingB and SomethingC. If algorithm is related to the combination of ItemBase, DueToBase and SomethingBase then it gets messy.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say Strategy Pattern

```
abstract class ItemBase {
  public DueToBase myDueToBase;
  public void partOfTheAlgorithmThatOnlySpecificIBKnows();
}

class Modified extends ItemBase {
  public void partOfTheAlgorithmThatOnlySpecificIBKnows() {
     //stuff only Modified knows
  }
}


abstract class DueToBase {
    public void partOfTheAlgorithmThatOnlySpecificDTBKnows();
}

class Provider extends DueToBase {
 //relevant code
  public ItemBase myItemBase;
  public void partOfTheAlgorithmThatOnlySpecificDTBKnows(){
       //stuff only provider knows
  }

  public void compute() {
       //you can also pass this but pointless since you all ready have the reference
       myItemBase.partOfTheAlgorithmThatOnlySpecificIBKnows();
       //some more code
  }
}

ItemBase ib = new Added();
ib.changed = new Provider(ib);
ib.changed.compute();
```

In the example this will call:

```
1. compute on Provider
2. part of the algorithm that Modified knows how to calculate
3. rest of the code for the algorithm
```

so at the `compute` function you have all the specific methods you need for the inherited classes and you can vary the algorithm in the `compute()` function.

If this doesn't solve your problem you might just have to figure a new design looking at the requirements as Owl said.

---

Also has no ifs but has more methods in which you are kind of doing the same thing has with the ifs, you are just letting the Inheritance mechanism do it for you.

Comment: this would be perfect solution in case when ItemBase has independent part of algorithm and we do not care about which type of instance is assigned to myItemBase, so we can just fire and forget.  
In my case it is important to be aware of which ItemBase derived classe is assigned to myItemBase property.  

...  
`public void compute() {  
   if(this.myItemBase is Cancelled)  
      doA();  
   else if(this.myItemBase is Modified)  
      doB();  
   else   
      doC();  
}`

Comment: hmm...you can solve that passing `this` to the DueToBase, has in `this.myItemBase.figureWhatToDo()` if its `canceled` on `figureWhatToDo()` you call `myDueToBase.doA()`, repeat for the others

Answer (score 1):

you can do so:

```
interface Algorithm {
    void executeAlgorithm(DueToBase dueToBase);
}
```

and have map

```
Map<Class, Algorithm> algorithmMap = new HashMap<Class, Algorithm>();
```

you will have classes for each algorithm

for example:

```
/**
  * this class is, for example, when itemBase instanceof Cancelled 
  */
class Algorithm1 implements Algorithm {

    public void executeAlgorithm(DueToBase dueToBase) {
        if ( dueToBase instanceof Provider ) {
            someAlgorithm();  // the algorithm specified somewhere, for provider
        } else if ( dueToBase instanceof Company ) {
            anotherAlgorithm(); // the algorithm or Company.
    }

    // this someAlgorithm() and anotherAlgorithm() are not same for different Algorithm classes
}
```

somewhere you must build algorithmMap.

```
algorithmMap.add( Cancelled.class , new Algorithm1() );
algorithmMap.add( Modified.class , new Algorithm2() );
algorithmMap.add( Added.class , new Algorithm3() );
```

and in doSomething method you won't have to write if-else blocks

```
doSomething() {
    Algorithm algorithm = algorithmMap.get( itemBase.getClass() );

    algorithm.executeAlgorithm(dueToBase);
}
```

in my opinion this is one of good oop solutions of this problem.

Comment: if dueToBase instanceof variants are many, this solution will also be bad. in that case, you can do the same logic in doSomething method ( another hashMap and algorithms ). or you can do [chain of responsibility](http://www.oodesign.com/chain-of-responsibility-pattern.html), each handler will check one dueToBase instanceof.